# How to set different provisioning profile based on my bundle identifier id on every azure devops build pipeline?

Tags: ios, azure, react-native, azure-devops, pipeline

I have developed an ios app using react-native. Now I want to generate a new app on every build by changing the app name and bundle identifier id. Rest of the source code will the same.

I have used azure devops for building my source code. Pipeline work fine with the same provisioning profile. But I want to set a new provisioning profile based on my identifier id which is set on pipeline variable.

Comment: Where you specify the provisioning profile? can you share the pipeline?

Comment: under the Install Apple Provisioning Profile Task,

Task YAML:
`steps:
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: '86598cea-b0ab-49a7-8274-6d2d4b2f79f0'`
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops

Comment: the identifier id it's a variable? (do you define it in the "variables section"?)